# text below an image HTML

Tags: html, css

I am having a difficult problem which I can't solve properly. I am trying to design a web page. I came up with a problem and I can't find the solution. I have two pics in my web page. I want them to be in the center of the page. It is quite diffcult to set the image float left and then right and then bottom. That is too difficult for me. and then my second problem is I want a text below my image.
But I can't do that because it is difficult to set the text position like "left:20x: "right:20px; and blah blah.

Comment: Help us help you and instead of the "blah blah"s actually try to explain your problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Set the positions of the images to relative `style="position:relative;"` then use right and left to move them from side to side (top and bottom to move them up and down). You can also put your text in a < div > and move it separately.

If after this you are still unsure, please enter your code and I'll examine it to make any modifications required.

EDIT: Here's an example of the CSS code I'm suggestions you use, in case you didn't understand what I meant:

`style="position:relative;left:10px;top:35px;"` Put this in the img tag and it would alter the position of your image by 10 pixels to the right and 35 pixels downwards.